# Delete lines from file unless it starts with specific string

Tags: powershell

If I have just one side of the `-or` statement it works but with it as is the output file only has one line that says `true`.

How would I make it show the lines that start with either of the specified lines?

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\carst\Desktop\temp.xml") -match "<Module" -or (Get-Content "C:\Users\carst\Desktop\temp.xml") -match "<description>" | Out-File "C:\Users\carst\Desktop\temp2.xml"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it's a XML file, you need to check if there are spaces before the node.

You can join the 2 searches and also check if there are spaces or not at the beginning with `^\s*`:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\carst\Desktop\temp.xml") -match '^\s*<(Module|description)' | Out-File "C:\Users\carst\Desktop\temp2.xml"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join them all in one match using the pipe character:

```
(Get-Content "C:\Users\carst\Desktop\temp.xml") -match '<Module|<description>' | 
Out-File "C:\Users\carst\Desktop\temp2.xml
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The output file still just said "True"